# How to solve this error while running reactnative project for the first time

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I am creating this project for the first time and running it causes some error which I can't solve.

This is `package.json` file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "expo": "^48.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-router": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "name": "reactnativejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true
}
```

This is the first error i got when i try `npm start`

[image]

This is the second error when I try to install `reactnative@0.71.4`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a confilict in dependenceies. Here is how to fix it:

1. delete node_modules and package-lock.json
2. run `npm cache clean --force` on terminal
3. run `npm install`

These three steps will fix the issue and the app will run correctly.